# Google Sheets IF formula based on dropdown data?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm too dull to figure this out..

I have a company that cleans apartments once tenants move out.

I need to express a project duration limit in a cell based on a dropdown list (apartment configuration types, i.e. Studio = 3 hours, 1 Bed/1Bath = 4 hours)

I've attached the screenshot of where we are so far...

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYNv4.png)

Can someone help w/ expressing the IF formula?

I tried the expression if("D2=studio","E2=3") to begin. I can't even get a number to populate at this point. I also need that duration limit to read as a number formatted as duration.

Comment: The formula is not written in the correct format.  In addition, this would require multiple nested `IF` statements or multiple `IFS`.  See my answer below for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would set it up.  On a separate tab (called "Duration" for example), list all your configurations in column A and the duration allotted to each one in column B.  Format column B as duration.  Write the time in this format `hh:mm:ss`.

Here is a screenshot of "Duration" tab:

[image: Shot1]

Then, in the tab where you want your formula, I added number of cleaners to column L just as an example.  Then I formatted column E2:E as duration and put the following formula in E2.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(L2:L=1,VLOOKUP(D2:D,Duration!A2:C,2,FALSE),IF(L2:L=2,VLOOKUP(D2:D,Duration!A2:C,3,FALSE),)))`

(I am judging from your screenshot, that the formula will go in E2 and the lookup range is D2:D.)  You may have to modify your lookup range of D2:D and the range that shows the number of cleaners if this is not how your spreadsheet is arranged.

Here is a screenshot of that tab:

[image: Shot2]

This is essentially, what the formula is saying:  If the number of cleaners in column L is 1, find value in "Duration" tab that matches configuration and duration for 1 cleaner.  If the number of cleaners in column L is 2, then find value in "Duration" tab that matches configuration and duration for 2 cleaners.  If the number of cleaners is neither, leave the cell blank.  This will avoid FALSE values at the bottom of your sheet where there is no other data.

Hopefully this helps.  Let me know!  Feel free to comment if you need further assistance.